# Bundler error on deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, macos, bundler, guard

I'm currently using guard i.e. guard-coffeescript gem to compile my javascript (and in the future I'll probably add some more guard tasks) on my OSX dev system. I added the `rb-fsevent` gem to my Gemspec, now I saw that in a lot of Gemspecs it is added with an if statement like this:

```
gem 'rb-fsevent', :require => false if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /darwin/i
```

Trying to deploy to my staging/production environment, which is running under Linux, the script executed on the server uses the `bundle install --deployment` results in following exception:

```
# bundle install --deployment
You have modified your Gemfile in development but did not check
the resulting snapshot (Gemfile.lock) into version control

You have deleted from the Gemfile:
* rb-fsevent
```

Is there a way around this problem or do I just have to remove the if so that I can deploy to my system and in turn installing a gem that is useless on a non OSX platform?

--

edit: I run `bundle install` before deploying to my staging environment and run `bundle check` after the first time it failed. I got it running after removing the if statement..

Comment: I don't understand why the if RUBY_PLATFORM condition isn't in the Gemfile.lock?  When you do bundle install on the server doesn't it just look at the Gemfile.lock?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I had a similar problem. If you're using capistrano you can set the following option:

```
set :bundle_without, [:darwin, :development, :test]
```

Then wrap your gem 'rb-fsevent' line in a group called darwin. Something like this should work nicely:

```
group :test, :darwin do
  gem 'rb-fsevent'
end
```

This makes bundler do this on the server:

```
bundle --without darwin development test
```

Which means that it ignores those groups in the Gemfile.lock. What you were doing would make you OS X machine and your server come up with different resulting lock files. Which is why it was complaining.

Comment: thanks for the tip, really seems there is no way how to do it with bundle install --deployment.

Comment: That gave me an error for some reason, but this worked `set :bundle_without, %w{darwin development test}.join(' ')`. It might be a capistrano 3 thing.

Comment: Take @David advice seriously and remove `:require => false if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /darwin/i`

Answer (score 6):

I had the exact same issue and Luke's solution fixed it for me, however, only after I removed the `:require => false if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /darwin/i` string that is commonly used.

Answer (score 2):

As described in

https://github.com/guard/guard

the solution is simply

```
group :development do
  gem 'rb-inotify', :require => false
  gem 'rb-fsevent', :require => false
  gem 'rb-fchange', :require => false
end
```

Comment: This worked for me (just removing the `if RUBY_PLATFORM...` part of the line).