# Gemfile.lock and gem's specific platform dependency?

Tags: capistrano, bundler

My `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` is in `Git` repository like http://gembundler.com/deploying.html

I use `'rbconfig'` for prevent to load `rb-fsevent` on linux production server but capistrano fail on executing command `'bundle install'`

I use capistrano with require `'bundler/capistrano'`

See stack trace :

```
You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
Your Gemfile. Run 'bundle install' elsewhere and add the
Updated Gemfile.lock to version control.

You have deleted from the Gemfile:
rb-fsevent
```

in my `Gemfile` :

```
case HOST_OS
  when /darwin/i
    gem "rb-fsevent"
end
```

How to avoid this?

Comment: I think this SO question will answer your problem:

[Bundler error on deployment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472785/bundler-error-on-deployment)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same exact problem, it appears that bundler already [resolved this](https://trello.com/c/Sh1xnJSi/76-add-install-if-dsl), but is not well documented.

Try with `install_if` and a lambda:

```
gem 'rb-fsevent', install_if: ->() { `uname` =~ /darwin/i }
```

Answer (score 0):

On Capistrano, you can set an option like `set :bundle_without, [:darwin]` to skip certain groups while bundling your gems in production.

Try assigning the gem to a group: `gem "rb-fsevent", group: :darwin` in your Gemfile and try again after doing `$ bundle` on your local machine && pushing to your remote repository.